# regex- the longest possible value

Tags: c#, regex

How to set regex to search the longest possible value? For example:

```
Regex.Match("theValue","(the|theValue)"); // this return "the", but "theValue" is longer match, and it can match too
```

or

```
Regex.Match("the Value","(the|the Value)"); // return "the", not "the Value"
Regex.Match("the Value","[t]?[h]?[e]?"); // return "t", not longer "the"
```

Comment: `Match` will only match one occurrence. If you want to match multiple you need `Matches`. See my update answer with an example.

Comment: You want to match both 'the' and 'the Value'?

Comment: Try to change "theValue" to "the Value", it returns "the" and "the"

Comment: When I test the [t]?[h]?[e]? pattern, it works just fine for me. What are the actual regexes and inputs you are using?

Answer (score 3):

Change your pattern to

```
\b(the|theValue)\b
```

or for your updated sample

```
\b(the Value|the)\b
```

In

> the and also theValue

Will match "the" (first on the left) and "theValue" (at the end).

Example:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = "the and also theValue";
        var pattern = @"\b(the|theValue)\b";

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> the
>   theValue

Comment: Ok, but it is not I want. This pattern was only the example. egex.Match("the Value","\b(the|the Value)\b"); will not work correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can't get overlapping matches, your first alternating pattern `the` causes that the second can't match (`the` from input string is already taken).

If you want the longest possible match you should start with the longest pattern: `"(theValue|the)"`.

btw `Regex.Match` returns only 1 match, if you want a collection that could be sorted by length you should use `Regex.Matches`.

Comment: @Mayo: standard regex engines already return the longest possible match, though the rules for how that actually works out can create some apparent counter-examples, such as the one with the two alternants that start with the same prefix.

Answer (score 0):

make `theValue` come first.

```
Regex.Match("theValue","(theValue|the)"); // returns theValue

Regex.Match("the Value","(theValue|the)"); // returns the
```

Comment: It works on this example but what if the pattern will be "([t]?[h]?[e]?)" .. it returns t, but the longest possible match is the